# Mapping domains to Tomcat Apps

Tags: java, linux, apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I have a server with CentOS and zpanel installed. Zpanel installed "Apache Httpd" along many other modules. I have been hosting multiple domains without any issue.

I have two issues:

1. Remove port 8080 and direct all calls to 80.
2. Appropriate domain for each tomcat app, as well as my existing sites running independently on Apache Http.

I installed apache tomcat 8 and deployed multiple applications and I can access my applications like

```
http://example:8080/app1
http://example:8080/app2
http://example:8080/app3
```

What I want is that my tomcat apps are mapped to my domains, such that

```
http://example:8080/app1 => http://www.app1.com
http://example:8080/app2 => http://www.app2.com
http://example:8080/app3 => http://www.app3.com
```

I did tried this [tutorial](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_7_on_centos]) which somewhat does trick but not exactly what I want. i.e. after performing the steps he mentioned when I opened my example.com it redirected to my tomcat app like: example.com/app1. [It did removed 8080 and redirected to correct app] BUT if the app from the end is changed i.e. app1 is changed to someother project that is been hosting by tomcat then that project is opened.

#### Edit:

My virtual host file is

```
 # DOMAIN: app1.com
 <virtualhost *:80>
 ServerName app1.com
 ServerAlias app1.com www.app1.com

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/$ app1/ [R=301]

     <Proxy *>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     </Proxy>

 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1
 ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1


 ErrorLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/app1.com-error.log"
 CustomLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/app1.com-access.log" combined
 CustomLog "/var/zpanel/logs/domains/zadmin/app1.com-bandwidth.log" common

 </virtualhost>
```

#### Update 1

I tried [this](http://www.jvmhost.com/knowledgebase/article/207/how-to-map-a-domain-to-tomcat-s-web-application-/) as well, but of no use. Am I missing something? please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 Days of hard search and lots of tests I was finally able to map my domain to tomcat app. Many thanks to these two guides [mod_jk installation](http://www.bluhm-de.com/installing-mod_jk-for-apache-2.2-on-centos-6) and [vhost/httpd/tomcat](http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/03/virtual-host-apache-httpd-server-tomcat.html)

Comment: I am having the same problem - Is your virtualhost file the one that worked for you? Because I tried it, and it still doesn't work as it should

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured properly your http server ?

For example in your apache2.conf or httpd.conf

```
 #LoadModule directives
 LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
 LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/app1
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8080/app1

    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app1/

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I just updated my question. please check. P.S with these configs it still shows me http://example.com/app1/ :(

Comment: With your config, you try to access to your apps by this url > http://app1.localhost, look at my config, there are some importante difference

Comment: Change your ServerName directive to ServerName www.app1.com and remove your ServerAlias