# Delegate specific URL request to specific Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Taking forward from my last question i.e. [Mapping domains to Tomcat Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228907/mapping-domains-to-tomcat-apps/). Now I want that if a particular request came i.e.

```
http://www.app1.com/blog
```

then this would be redirected to a specific folder on my server. I did tried below code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/blog/ /path_to_my_site/app1_com/blog/ [L]
```

but that has gone horribly wrong as that has become redirect loop, so I removed it immediately.

**Note:** My site www.app1.com is hosting java application and www.app1.com/blog would be php application blog.

#### Update 1

for the sake of clarity below is my virtual host configuration

```
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName app1.com
ServerAlias app1.com www.app1.com


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ /path_to_my_site/blog/ [L,NC]

ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/app1/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/app1/

</virtualhost>
```

#### Update 2

contents of .htaccess in blog folder is

```
# Pretty Permalinks
RewriteRule ^(images)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^action=logout [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^action=login [NC]
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?filename=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ /path_to_my_site/app1_com/blog/ [L,NC]
```

`/path_to_my_site/app1_com/blog/` should be a valid path under `DocumentRoot`.

Change your `ProxyPass` line to this:

```
ProxyPass /blog !
ProxyPassMatch ^/(?!blog).*$ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/app1/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/app1/
```

Comment: It's not working properly, I tried your code and by browsing http://app1.com/blog it still maps to my java app.

Comment: yes /path_to_my_site/app1_com/blog/ is real directory where php files are placed.

Comment: multiple domains are running on my server but as you can see that the rule you mentioned was the first rule in that domain context.

Comment: Do you want only one domain to use this rule? Is there any .htaccess in `/blog/` folder?

Comment: In future their would be more domains that would also have that rule so that a specific request for blog folder matches to specific directory. I don't think there would be any problem as each domain configuration reside in separate virtual host tags. Regarding second question, I have updated my question.

Comment: Wow you have rewrite rules even before `RewriteEngine on` in `/blog/.htaccess`

Comment: well that was written automatically by blogging software, not me.

Comment: no it isn't. An error page is shown which is configured on app1.com when I try to access http://app1.com/blog

Comment: Whatever it is doing or not doing but having rewrite rules before `RewriteEngine On` is wrong.

Comment: Also if you have .htaccess in `/blog/` then you don't need any rule. Opening `http://www.app1.com/blog` will by default open default handling in `/blog/` directory.

Comment: I disabled .htaccess in blog folder and pasted your rules in virtual host files, but it's still not working. it still shows me the error page of my java application.

Comment: Let's discuss this issue in more detail here [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66592/discussion-between-waqar-and-anubhava)